# Custom drop down controller issue in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using the custom dropdown in my mobile app. The problem is when the list of that dropdown is empty then i am showing a container in the place of that dropdown. When the list has element again, customdropdown is again shown but when i select an option of that dropdown for the first time the onChanged method is not called and sometimes refreshereportanalysisfilter() is called multiple time regardless of onChanged getting called only once. My full Code is attached here.

```
_subjectsList.isNotEmpty
                                      ? SizedBox(
                                          // key: Key(myKey),
                                          width: _width * 0.35,
                                          height: 30.0,
                                          child: CustomDropdown(
                                            // key: Key(myKey),
                                            hintText: 'Select',
                                            fillColor: ThemeColors.offwhite,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: ThemeColors.secondary,
                                                width: 1.5),
                                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: ThemeColors.black,
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                            selectedStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: ThemeColors.black,
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                            listItemStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: ThemeColors.black,
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                            items:
                                                // ["Select"],
                                                _subjectsList.cast<String>(),
                                            controller: _subjectController,
                                            onChanged: (value) async {
                                              await refreshReportAnalysiswithFilter();
                                              if (mounted) setState(() {});
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Container(
                                          height: 30.0,
                                          width: _width * 0.35,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: ThemeColors.offwhite,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                            border: Border.all(
                                              color: ThemeColors.secondary,
                                              width: 1.5,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 14.0),
                                            child: Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  "Select",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: ThemeColors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 13,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w500),
                                                ),
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  size: 19.0,
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        )
```

Whenever i am assigning the _subjectController a new controller its working but i want to know what is causing the issues and what will be the best practice to resolve it.

Comment: Your widget is too long which is not a good practice. I suggest you break down your code into pieces and post only the relevant code that causing an error.

Comment: i have made it short and the relevant widget is only posted